# How to loop through multiple layers in a GeoPackage using QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have 1,366 districts each of which has up to 300 sub-districts. These are all held in a GeoPackage, but each district is a separate layer.

What I need to do next is to iterate through each layer and apply MULTIPART TO SINGLEPART (and other operations) to the sub-districts.

I will need to this in Graphical Modeller.

So far, I have only been able to address the first layer in the GeoPackage. How do I loop through all the layers in the GeoPackage?

QGIS 3.10.3 A Coruna
Window 10 (64-bit)

Answer (score 5):

First add them all to your project. You can disable rendering to prevent QGIS slowing down and drawing all stuff before. Uncheck on the bottom right of QGIS:

[image]

Select all layers and add them:

[image]

Open your model and click on "run as batch process":

[image]

Then load all open layers. Unfortunately there is no option (at least in 3.10 LTR) to select all layers of one file in another way. Thats why you had to add them all to your project first...

[image]

Comment: Thank you - looks like that's it.

Comment: @BruceMitchell Seems like, unfortunately. Not really satisfying and maybe worth a feature request (ability to load several layers from one file directly in processing batch).